# How to call this function in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that I want to call in HTML. Can anyone help?
This is my function:

```js
function editLevel(id) {
  var result = '';

  result =
    '<button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="ویرایش مقادیر سطح کاربری" onclick="DefaultModal(\'ویرایش مقادیر\', \'EditLevel/' +
    id +
    '\')" style="margin-left: 5px"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>';
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a button

```
<button onclick='editLevel(/* id */)'></button>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesen't open the modal

Comment: @Ashkan AA Add a `document.getElementById('/* any id of container */ ').innerHTML = result;` in the function editLevel.

Comment: Still doesn't help

Comment: Then actually what do you want, @AshkanAA ? can you explain more so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You could use document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction) and it will execute your function when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Onetest() {
        let A, B, C, D, result;

        A = 46;
        B = 64;
        C = 43;
        D = 24;

        result = A + B + C + D;

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
    }

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Onetest()">
```